# How to send a direccion to the void using the Hosts file and without using 127.0.0.1?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sharepoint-2010, hosts-file

I have some name address that i want to send straight to the **void** using the HOSTS file but i don't want to use the 127.0.0.1. How can i do that?.

Why?, I want to speed up some proccess but 127.0.0.1 is serving a webserver, so if i use 127.0.0.1 then this process will call my webserver, consuming resources and may be delaying the process.

Right now, i am using 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 but i am not sure if it is correct.

```
    0.0.0.0  crl.microsoft.com
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

- Is your web server listening on 127.0.0.2 as well?
- 0.0.0.0 should be fine, though you're likely generating some short-lived network traffic with it.

Comment: Your first point was going to be my answer too. There are hundreds of loopback addresses, and only one of them is ever used in 99.99% of cases.

Comment: @MarkHenderson a bit more then hundreds.  You have an entire `/8` there is 16,777,214 possible addresses.